# Magento 2 Rest Api call curl SSL Error

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, curl-request

I have setup a custom Magento Rest Api at the endpoint: "https://domain-name.de/rest/V1/wawi". This Api just returns a simple json string. Have tested my Api with Postman application -> works fine.

The problem occurs, when I test it in PHP script:

```
 $curl = curl_init();

 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => "https://domain-name.de/rest/V1/wawi",
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
 CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"p\":\"test\"}",
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
 "cache-control: no-cache",
 "content-type: application/json",
 ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
 echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

RESULT:

cURL Error #:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Any ideas on how to solve this issue ?

**EDIT**
Just checked my magento server is using "OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 openssl version number: 268439647" and my client is using "OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015 openssl version number: 268439743"

Answer (score 0):

please add `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION =>3`

Comment: Thx for the reply. Added and got new error message: cURL Error #:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Comment: Tried also with 2, message:  cURL Error #:OpenSSL was built without SSLv2 support

Comment: magento ver 1.9.2.3,I am work with REST API in POSTMAN, i have all oAuth 1.0 details like Consumer Key,Consumer Secret,Access Token,Token Secret. Now i moved to oAuth 2.0, how can i get my all oAuth 2.0 details? @Nalin Savaliya

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason for using the following lines:

```
 CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
 CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
```

Try removing all these lines, or, if you prefer, test removing one by one.

Comment: Let me know if this solves you issue. If negative I will take a deeper analysis.